# angular 6 with identity server 4

Tags: angular6, identityserver4

i'm trying to setup angular 6 in visual studio code that uses identity server 4 as authentication component. Which libraries for client side (angular) are best to quick setup authentication logic with is4? which kind of authentication flow should be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

For the client side libraries, try https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js

Also, the new recommendation is to use PKCE when using a SPA.  See IdentityServer4 docs([ref](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html))

There is also a great post at https://damienbod.com/2016/10/01/identityserver4-webapi-and-angular2-in-a-single-asp-net-core-project/

Comment: Is this library better than: https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client ?